# App Invites on Android keeps Loading forever

Tags: android, google-app-invites

I'm trying to use Google App Invites on Android... I followed the tutorial, but when I get the invite screen, it shows the title only, and remains loading the rest of the content forever. See imagem below:

[image]

All I could get from the stacktrace was this:

```
11-24 12:35:53.489 649-966/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ACTION_APP_INVITE dat=https://fleeber.com/appInvite.jpg pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.appinvite.AppInviteActivity (has extras)} from uid 10365 on display 0
11-24 12:35:53.644 649-1430/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.google.android.gms.ui for activity com.google.android.gms/.appinvite.AppInviteActivity: pid=20632 uid=10057 gids={50057, 9997, 2001, 3003, 1007, 3006, 1028, 1015, 3002, 3001, 1005, 3007} abi=armeabi-v7a

11-24 12:35:55.030 649-676/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.google.android.gms/.appinvite.AppInviteActivity: +1s418ms

11-24 12:35:55.405 649-676/system_process I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{1beedbed u0 com.google.android.gms/.appinvite.AppInviteActivity t590} time:60595587
```

I'm using the google-services:1.3.1 and play-services:8.3.0

I have tried this on my debug version fo the app and also on my release... maybe something wrong with the google-services.json?

In the json I got this:

```
{"project_info":{"project_id":"xxxxxxx","project_number":"xxxxxx","name":"fleeber"},"client":[{"client_info":{"mobilesdk_app_id":"xxxxxxx","client_id":"android:com.fleeber","client_type":1,"android_client_info":{"package_name":"com.fleeber"}},"oauth_client":[{"client_id":"xxxxxxxxxx","client_type":1,"android_info":{"package_name":"com.fleeber","certificate_hash":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"client_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","client_type":1,"android_info":{"package_name":"com.fleeber.debug","certificate_hash":"xxxxxxxxxxx"}}],"api_key":[],"services":{"analytics_service":{"status":2,"analytics_property":{"tracking_id":"xxxxxxxxx"}},"cloud_messaging_service":{"status":2,"apns_config":[]},"appinvite_service":{"status":2,"other_platform_oauth_client":[{"client_id":"xxxxxxxxxx","client_type":2,"ios_info":{"bundle_id":"com.fleeber.prod","app_store_id":""}}]},"google_signin_service":{"status":2},"ads_service":{"status":1}}}],"client_info":[],"ARTIFACT_VERSION":"1"}
```

Any ideias?

**EDITED -** Solved by updating libraries as described in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

For future references... the problem has been solved by changing the version of the google-services:1.3.1 on the project build.gradle to google-services:1.5.0-beta2